# How can i print and play sound at the same time? (winsound)

Tags: python, winsound

I'm trying to make a morse code machine that plays the beep and then prints the morse code. Instead, it plays all the sounds and only then prints the message. pls help.
code:
(lettr2morse is a dictionary that has letters turned into morse)

```
    morse_counter2 = 0
    morse_counter = 0
    morse_input = input("\nwhat would you like to tarnslate?\n")
    for r in range(len(morse_input)):
        morse = letter2morse.get(morse_input[morse_counter])
        for r in range (len(morse)):
            if morse[morse_counter2] == "-":
                winsound.Beep(750, 500)
                print("-", end="")
            else:
                winsound.Beep(750, 150)
                print(".", end="")
            morse_counter2 += 1
        time.sleep (1.5)
        morse_counter += 1
        morse_counter2 = 0
        print(" ", end="")
```

Comment: You could try using multiprocessing

Answer (score 1):

Try the built in module, [threading](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwicyNLbsuvpAhXxRt8KHUnqBhsQFjAAegQICRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python.org%2F3%2Flibrary%2Fthreading.html&usg=AOvVaw1tCkviFnKtBD3PXP9vezCC):

```
from threading import Thread
import winsound

def sound():
    winsound.Beep(750, 500)

Sound = Thread(target=sound)

Sound.start()
print("-")
```